# If my main skill is javascript than which other skills would complement it best

Tags: javascript

So if i excel at javascript than learning what other libraries, languages, framework, business related things would help me improve as a developer and get hired.

I know just knowing js isn't enough and that developer must know some basic stuff like
jquery, css3, html5, etc.

But what else.

I rarely see a job in which it says you need to know javascript there are always a lot of something else.

Comment: [so] is not a career advice site.

Comment: You should know that this is open ended irrelevant question here. You should probably ask this to somewhere like reddit.com or quora.com.

Comment: i kinda figured that. But if someone can just say anything i'd be nice. Like as of now what things you think are important that a web dev should know

Comment: The same account you use here will work at both [the workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and at [programmers stack exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Your question might be a better match at one of those sites. Here it is off topic.

Comment: is it possible to transfer it there programmer.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is not the perfect place to ask this question but to help you I would like to suggest you some options.
If you are aiming to become a full-time front-end developer then along with the Javascript you must have excellent knowledge of HTML5, CSS3 and JQuery.
Also you must start practicing  at least two of the following JavaScript frameworks:
Angular JS,
Node JS,
Grunt,
Dojo,
MooTools.

It would be good to have knowledge of SASS & COMPASS as well.
A good knowledge of Photoshop or Illustrator is also required.

Rest you can research yourself and choose as per your choice.
Best of luck!!